# Why do DOMMarker and Marker appear to be placed differently on HERE map JS?

Tags: here-api

we are using HERE JS 3.0 and are trying to add a custom marker to our map.

I noticed that our custom SVG is always a little off-center and does not match up with where a "regular" Marker would be placed (the "regular" marker points to the correct location) even though the provided coords are the same:

http://jsfiddle.net/nptq0dk7/7/

[image]

(The above fiddle is using 3.1, but the same behavior is happening in 3.0 as well.)

```
  var icon = new H.map.DomIcon(svgMarkup);
  var domMarker = new H.map.DomMarker(coords, {icon: icon});
  map.addObject(domMarker);

  var regularMarker = new H.map.Marker(coords);
  map.addObject(regularMarker);
```

Any advice on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the DOM Marker is absolutely positioned with regard to parent container, you can use `left` and `right` CSS properties on the `<svg>` element. Like this:

```js
var svgMarkup = '<svg style="left: -12px; top: -12px;" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">' +
                  //...
                '</svg>'
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5rqgcjnh/)**

Answer (score 1):

Both your custom SVG and the regular Marker are both positioned at the same geocoordinates. The custom SVG seems off because it is a square and the top left of it is positioned at the specified geocoordinate whereas the regular Marker is placed with its pointed end at the geocoordinate. Please use CSS margin, to center the SVG.

[image]